# echo and add array keys

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

My Array:

```
<?php
    $fruitcolors = array('apple'=>'red', 'lemon'=>'yellow');
?>
```

I need to know how to echo the value of apple, so it echos "red".

Also I need to know how to add a new value with php code:

`$fruitcolors[] = "Pear" => "Green";` etc.

Comment: Uh... `echo $fruitcolors['apple'];`? And `$fruitcolors['Pear'] = 'Green';`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    // echo 'red'
    echo $fruitcolors['apple'];

    // assign key: 'Pear', value: 'Green'
    $fruitcolors['Pear'] = 'Green';
?>
```

See http://php.net/array for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Basic feature of arrays are clearly explained in the [manual](http://php.net/array):

```
echo $fruitcolors['apple'];
$fruitcolors['pear'] = 'green';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you google "php arrays" this is likely among the results:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php